# Django App Managing RAW SQLs best practices

Tags: python, django, django-templates

We have a Reporting Python Django Application. Application coded to have complex rollups, group by , join SQLs which is not truly ORM friendly. so we need up in having bunch of SQLs in the sql.py file. SQLs in thefile will have place holders which gets transformed , used django.connection to query database.

all template relays on the set of dict object from server side.  What are the good practices in managing such SQLs, View layer dict data.

Comment: any best practices around this question  would be good. !!!